# How does date manipulation/comparison/grouping work in SQL queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I need to analyze an SQL query (and construct its equivalent in MDX). I'm not familiar with SQL and can't access the database, so there are 5 simple things I can't figure out:

1. What does the part `WHERE idate BETWEEN trunc(SYSDATE, 'iw')-7 AND trunc(SYSDATE, 'iw')-3` mean? Specifically:

   - What does subtracting 7 from `trunc(SYSDATE, 'iw')` do? Subtract 7 weeks or 7 days? I understand the `trunc(...)` expression is a value 0-53 corresponding to the week of the year, but it seems to clash with the label "previous week" and stated purpose of the query.
   - How does SQL compare dates? Are the values from `trunc(...)` evaluated as dates during comparison?
2. The query seems to group rows together if they happened in the same minute. However, the few rows of output I can see have 10-minute granularity (00:00, 00:10, 00:20, etc.) Is there something in the query that groups rows into 10 minute intervals, or is this a result of the input data?
3. Why are calls to `substr()` and `to_char()` and needed in the group by condition? What would happen if `trunc(idate, 'HH24:MI')` was used instead?
4. What does the `pm` do? There is also a `cm` that seems to have a similar function. Are these part of the temporary table names?
5. Finally, how do the hash marks (#) affect this query? I read it might be to signify temporary tables. If so, are these temporary tables created manually, or does something in the query cause them to be created?

---

For reference here is the query. (On a Oracle database, if it makes any difference.) Its purpose is to "analyze how firewall accept events are trending compared to last week":

```
SELECT   'Previous Week Average' AS term , 
         Substr(To_char(idate, 'HH24:MI'), 0, 4) 
                  || '0'        AS event_time , 
         Round(Avg(tot_accept)) AS cnt 
FROM     ( 
                SELECT                     * 
                FROM   st_event_100_#yyyymm-1m# 
                WHERE  idate BETWEEN trunc(SYSDATE, 'iw')-7 AND    trunc(SYSDATE, 'iw')-3 #stat_monitor_group_query#
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT * 
                FROM   st_event_100_#yyyymm# 
                WHERE  idate BETWEEN trunc(SYSDATE, 'iw')-7 AND    trunc(SYSDATE, 'iw')-3 #stat_monitor_group_query# ) pm
GROUP BY substr(to_char(idate, 'HH24:MI'), 0, 4) 
                  || '0' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT   'Today' AS term , 
         substr(to_char(idate, 'HH24:MI'), 0, 4) 
                  || '0'        AS event_time , 
         round(avg(tot_accept)) AS cnt 
FROM     st_event_100_#yyyymm# cm 
WHERE    idate >= trunc(SYSDATE) #stat_monitor_group_query# 
GROUP BY substr(to_char(idate, 'HH24:MI'), 0, 4) 
                  || '0' 
ORDER BY term DESC, 
         event_time ASC
```

Comment: You can have Oracle database without installing it on your machine. There is a nice Oracle service https://livesql.oracle.com you can play with Oracle SQL. All you need is register for Oracle account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `iw` truncates the date to the first day of the calendar week as defined by the ISO 8601 standard, which is Monday. When you subtract numbers from the date, it is always the number of days. So, `idate BETWEEN trunc(SYSDATE, 'iw')-7 AND trunc(SYSDATE, 'iw')-3` gives you those dates that fall between previous week's Monday and Friday.
2. `to_char(idate, 'HH24:MI')` gives you the time(hour and minute) part in 24hr format. Ex: `14:33`. By using substrin to extract only 4 characters, you are actually getting `14:3`. So yes, this groups with a granularity of 10 mins.
3. You cannot write `trunc(idate, 'HH24:MI')`.  It can only have 1 [precision specifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions255.htm#SQLRF52058).

   If you write `trunc(idate,'HH24')`, it truncates to the hour. If you use `MI`, it truncates to the minute. So, to truncate it to 10 mins is a little tricky.
4. `pm` is just an alias for the whole subquery.

   `SELECT     * 
    FROM   st_event_100_#yyyymm-1m# 
     ......
    WHERE  idate BETWEEN trunc(SYSDATE, 'iw')-7 AND    trunc(SYSDATE, 'iw')-3     #stat_monitor_group_query#`
5. `#` is part of the table anme in your query. It has no significance as such. But, it might be project/company specific.